# Battery 0%, not charging. Shuts down during demanding tasks. ROG G751JY

Tags: laptop, battery, shutdown

So like 5 months ago my ROG didnt want to charge to 100% anymore. I didnt like it but never used it without the AC, so I didnt think much of it. So I went away for a week so i disconnected the AC - when I came back the battery was dead. It says "0% avaliable (plugged in, charging). Its not really a big deal since I always use it with the AC, but recently when I am gaming the laptop just turns off. I can turn it on right away - so it seems it loses power for half a second or something, which is enough to turn it off.

Seems like my battery serve more of a purpose other than running with no AC. And should provide extra current during high demand usage like heavy gaming, and also carry you through brownouts.

Anybody managed to fix this without opening the thing and replacing it with a 100 euro battery?

Comment: Powerful laptop computers often require more power than the shipped PSU can provide. That’s why the battery is required. You must replace the battery. 100 € is a little on the expensive side but nonetheless normal for high-capacity battery packs.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. The sad part is that I'd have to open the computer to replace the battery, which will void the warranty (which I can't use since I am not living in the country I bought the computer in).

Answer (score 1):

A dead battery can easily trick the power supply logic into a `not enough power` state.
When gaming, it is absolutely possible, that a spike in power consumption overloads the AC power supply, taking energy from the battery for a few milliseconds. If this fails, the PSL will shut it down. A second after the load spike, these few joules will charge back into the battery.

The fact, that meager AC power supplies can barely power the Laptop under full load (leaving no headroom to charge the battery) is one of the reasons, why business class notebooks often come with different sizes of AC adapters, a light (but meager) one for the road and a true flying brick for the office.

Comment: Thats what I feared. Is there any way to alter this so it never goes to the battery for the extra energy? Just to make it clear my AC is stock - it came with the laptop. Its big and heavy as a brick.

Comment: Big and heavy doesn't equal to powerful, sorry. You can try a different power supply, that has (**IMPORTANT**) the same Voltage +/- 0.2 Volts, but a higher value of Amperes or Watts, whatever is printed on it.

Comment: Haha, its true. But for me its seems like a very cynical marketing strategy from them. 1. when the battery stops to work the AC isnt powerful enough to power the computer. 2. the battery cant be removed unless I open the case and void the warranty... :/